# gnuplot low quality outputs

Tags: output, gnuplot

I have a problem with gnuplot's outputs. The produced plots are of low quality. When i export the plots from the gnuplot window as pdf, the images are crispy clear. If i export as png,the results are slightly blurry. Saving as either jpeg or png directly from the script, the images are even worse. Is there a way to produce clear jpeg or png images? The script and software i am using follow:

```
set title "Temperature-Specific entropy diagram"

set termopt enhanced

set grid

set key top left

set xlabel "Specific entropy [kJ/KgK]"
set ylabel "Temperature [^oC]"

set datafile missing '0.000000000000000000e+00'

plot "Ts_saturation_curve.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "saturation curve" with line lt 1 lw 1.5 lc rgb "black",\
     "critical_point.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "critical point" with points pt 6 ps 1.5 lc rgb "orangered4",\
     "isobaric_critical.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "isobaric critical" with line lt 1 lw 1.5 lc rgb "orangered4",\
     "isobaric_0.1MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "0.1 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "dark-red",\
     "isobaric_0.2MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "0.2 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "red",\
     "isobaric_0.5MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "0.5 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "orange",\
     "isobaric_1.0MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "1 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "yellow",\
     "isobaric_2.0MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "2 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "greenyellow",\
     "isobaric_5.0MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "5 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "green",\
     "isobaric_10.0MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "10 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "cyan",\
     "isobaric_20.0MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "20 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "blue",\
     "isobaric_50.0MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "50 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "violet",\
     "isobaric_100.0MPa.txt" using ($1/1000.0):($2-273.15) title "100 MPa" with line lt 1 dt 2 lc rgb "purple"

set term png
set output "output.png"
replot
```

gnuplot 5.2,debian 10.5 (cinnamon de)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your terminal size? `set term png size <x>,<y>`. Can you post an example output of a PNG?

Comment: If you mean my screen resolution, it is 1440x900. I used set size 1.0, 1.0
set term png size 1440, 900, but the images are still messed up. Meanwhile the pdf output is spotless. Even zoomed in. The following links contain the rest of the outputs. The first two are jpg,png outputs, while the third, which is the best, is the png extracted from the gnuplot window. It might not be clear but the lines in the first two are somewhat choppy while the third is slightly blurry. https://ibb.co/5GZCm3M
https://ibb.co/GWsfsVK
https://ibb.co/p1CB1nW

Comment: jpg is ok for photos but probably not for such graphs. All 3 graphs you uploaded have 640x480 px. Why? Shouldn't they have 1440x900? 640x480 look like a default size.

Comment: Yes, here i provide just a sample. Resolution makes no difference jpeg and png are still choppy. What format would you recommend? How would you set the output for maximum quality?

Comment: can you provide a 1440x900 PNG example?btw you can also add images here if you edit your question. I'm not sure but (maybe only with Windows) there is/was a `terminal png` and a `terminal pngcairo`. Not sure whether this is available in Linux. Could you try `set term pngcairo size 1440,900`?

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. Apparently set term pngcairo worked. Much oblidged!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of not letting this answer appear unanswered and furthermore according the SO "rule" "no answer in comments"...

Try this:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1440,900
```

Apparently, `term png` and `term pngcairo` are using different libraries with different quality results.